# Which way is more secure: apache:admin or folder group owner:apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, security, permissions, user-management

I have been learning in recent days how to set up var/www/ permissions.

I understand the common solution is set a group owner of all new folders to apache via sticky bit. How about giving the Apache the secondary group of "admin" to which certain users belong? It seems to be more flexible approach, as this way with all scripts uploaded by admins apache will have write permissions, while not with other, less trusted users.

What are the security vulnerabilities to this approach? How does it compare, in terms of security, to simply making owner of folders apache primary group - apache?

Comment: The general approach is to give the least amount of permission possible. if you give us specific use cases we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the owner `root:root` is probably the most "secure". It prevents anyone but root from changing the files.

Making the owner `apache:apache` allows only root or apache (and members of the apache group depending on permissions... same with above though... if you give the group write permissions.. that group gets write permissions..)

When we had multiple collaborators working on one of our bigger sites, we set it up so that apache was the owner and a group called `webdevel` was the owner. Both of these had write permissions....

Looking back, the most secure way to do this (While providing sanity for the developers) is probably to assign `root:admins` per your example to any files that `apache` itself does not need to write. If apache has write access to files, a compromise of the server will mean that the user can change whatever files needed as the `apache` user. You should consider protecting your web **files** from your web **server** for this reason. Just give apache ownership of config files it **NEEDS** to change or folders where it **NEEDS** to upload (such as an images upload directory).

Now if you have files that apache should not write to, but should be able to read.. but all other non-root&&non-admin users should **not** be able to read (config files with passwords), either:

1)adopt more complex ACLs

or

2) keep malicous untrustworthy off your server

or

3) keep untrustworthy users jailed.